# Is every mathematical object representable by sets?

Tags: set-theory

I know that most mathematical objects can be represented by a complex structure of sets. For example one can use [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers) for representing natural numbers:

$$\begin{align}
0 & = \{\} \\
1 & = \{0\} = \{\{\}\} \\
2 & = \{0,1\} = \{\{\},\{\{\}\}\} \\
& \vdots
\end{align}$$

For ordered pairs there is [Kuratowski's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition) $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, for real numbers [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) can be used and so on...

**My Question:** Is there any mathematical object which cannot be represented by a (complex) structure of sets?

I know that there are objects such as [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) for which no construction is known yet (the only introduction of hyperreals I know of uses the axiom of choice). But I guess, that one can show with ZFC that there must exist a complex structure of sets isomorph to the hyperreals.

**More precise question:** Is there a mathematical object for which one cannot prove with ZFC that there must exist a complex set structure which represents this object?

Comment: Well the collection of all ordinals is not a set. That seems like a mathematical object.

Comment: @PaulPlummer: Good point. So I have to concrete my question: I more thought of mathematical concepts which are used outside set theory like topological spaces, manifolds, ... So: Are there classes which are important outside set theory?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the suggestion, and there was another thread or two, but I found this link first.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks for pointing me to the linked thread! ;-)

Comment: Sure. Let me just point out that if you accept large cardinals as reasonable additions to ZFC, then classes and categories and so on can all be formalized in set theory. A multiverse approach works here as well, specifically the one Joel Hamkins suggests, where essentially every universe of set theory is a countable model in a larger universe, and so on.